# IE11 Flex issue with Bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

im experiencing a problem with IE11 and Flexbox when using bootstrap table.

My row looks like this

[image]

I have a table in the design that is scrollable to the right as there is a lot of fields in it. The flex with col setup make it to persist the column widths.

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox as seen on image bellow.

[image]

In IE though, its broken as the tbody row is moved differently against thead row. Both of them have the same structure and classes as on the first image.

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this? I have to support IE11 with current project and this is real pain.

UPDATE: 
Here is the code of the table:

```
<table class="table-responsive table-sm">
        <thead>
        <tr class="d-flex">
            <th class="col-1">Bla 1</th>
            <th class="col-2">Bla 2</th>
            <th class="col-2">Bla 3</th>
            <th class="col-2">Bla 4</th>
            <th class="col-2">Bla 5</th>
            <th class="col-1">Bla 6</th>
            <th class="col-1">Bla 7</th>
            <th class="col-3">Bla 8</th>
            <th class="col-3">Bla 9</th>
            <th class="col-1">Bla 10</th>
            <th class="col-3">Bla 11</th>
            <th class="col-3">Bla 12</th>
            <th class="col-3">Bla 13</th>
            <th class="col-3">Bla 14</th>
            <th class="col-2">15</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for item in bla %}
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-1">{{ item.bla1 }}</td>
                <td class="col-2"></td>
                <td class="col-2">{{ item.bla3 }}</td>
                <td class="col-2">{{ item.bla4 }}</td>
                <td class="col-2">{{ item.bla5 }}</td>
                <td class="col-1">{{ item.bla6 }}</td>
                <td class="col-1">{{ item.bla7 }}</td>
                <td class="col-3">{{ item.bla8 }}</td>
                <td class="col-3">{{ item.bla9 }}</td>
                <td class="col-1">{{ item.bla10 }}</td>
                <td class="col-3">{{ item.bla11 }}</td>
                <td class="col-3">{{ item.bla12 }}</td>
                <td class="col-3">{{ item.bla13 }}</td>
                <td class="col-3">{{ item.bla14 }}</td>
                <td class="col-2">{{ item.bla15 }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="14">no records found</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: IE11 doesn't fully support Flexbox:  https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox, _"Partial support is due to large amount of bugs present (see known issues)"_.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Is there some workaround?

Comment: Try adding `flex-shrink: 0` to the flex items.

Comment: @Michael_B did not help :(

Comment: Can you please put the full code of the table here?

Comment: @Α.Papadakis done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out using this style:

```
    td , th {
        display: block;
    }

    thead , tbody {
        display: flex;
    }

    tr {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Solution 2 would be to set a static width to every `col` like this:

```
th.col-1 , td.col-1 {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}

th.col-2 , td.col-2 {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
}

th.col-3 , td.col-3 {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Working code with solution 1:

```css
 td , th {
  display: block;
 }

 thead , tbody {
  display: flex;
 }

 tr {
  width: 100%;
 }
/*
 th.col-1 , td.col-1 {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
 }

 th.col-2 , td.col-2 {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
 }

 th.col-3 , td.col-3 {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
 }
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <style type="text/css">


  </style>
</head>
<body>

 <table class="table-responsive table-sm">
  <thead>
   <tr class="d-flex">
    <th class="col-1">Bla 1</th>
    <th class="col-2">Bla 2</th>
    <th class="col-2">Bla 3</th>
    <th class="col-2">Bla 4</th>
    <th class="col-2">Bla 5</th>
    <th class="col-1">Bla 6</th>
    <th class="col-1">Bla 7</th>
    <th class="col-3">Bla 8</th>
    <th class="col-3">Bla 9</th>
    <th class="col-1">Bla 10</th>
    <th class="col-3">Bla 11</th>
    <th class="col-3">Bla 12</th>
    <th class="col-3">Bla 13</th>
    <th class="col-3">Bla 14</th>
    <th class="col-2">Bla 15</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="d-flex">
    <td class="col-1">Bla 1</td>
    <td class="col-2">Bla 2</td>
    <td class="col-2">Bla 3</td>
    <td class="col-2">Bla 4</td>
    <td class="col-2">Bla 5</td>
    <td class="col-1">Bla 6</td>
    <td class="col-1">Bla 7</td>
    <td class="col-3">Bla 8</td>
    <td class="col-3">Bla 9</td>
    <td class="col-1">Bla 10</td>
    <td class="col-3">Bla 11</td>
    <td class="col-3">Bla 12</td>
    <td class="col-3">Bla 13</td>
    <td class="col-3">Bla 14</td>
    <td class="col-2">Bla 15</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Its working with one column, with more columns the tbody and thead needs to have flex-wrap: wrap; property :)

Comment: @MichalTakáč  Nice! :)